# convert any image format to pnm format in c#

Tags: c#, image, image-conversion

how to convert any images format to .pnm format ?
I see list of image format in `System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat`,  pnm format is not available in there. So, there is any way to convert the image to pnm format in c# ?

Comment: You have two options really. 1. Go find a library someone has written that you can call from within a C# app to do the conversion. 2. Build your own converter that takes the raw pixel array of an image and turns it into ASCII values.

Comment: The PNM family of formats are very simple and you can do this yourself in maybe 15 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this library, it could do what you want: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18061/Managed-PNM-Image-Reader-and-Writer